# error: not statement in java

Tags: java

This is the code snippet:

```
public class luas{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Data_lingkaran k = new Data_lingkaran();
        k.pi=3.14;
        k.jari1=12;
        k.jari2=12;
        k.luas;
        k.luas = k.pi * k.jari1 * k.jari2;
        System.out.println("Luas Lingkaran = " +k.luas);
    }
}
```

and the error says that:

```
 luas.java:7: error: not a statement
 k.luas;
 1 error
```

Comment: What was the purpose of `k.luas;`? It is not a statement as indicated by the error

Answer (score 2):

`k.luas;` its not valid statement, it should be either declaration or assignment. if `luas` is a field in `k`, then remove `k.luas;`

Comment: show another error after remove k.luas

`cannot find symbol`
Data_lingkaran k = new Data_lingkaran();

Answer (score 1):

Remove `k.luas;`, its a field in your class and it is not a valid statement.

Comment: show another error after remove k.luas

`cannot find symbol
Data_lingkaran k = new Data_lingkaran();'

Comment: @TitoMaizar Where is your class named `Data_lingkaran`? Did you compile it? Make sure it is available in the classpath when you compile class `luas`.

Answer (score 0):

`k.luas;` its not valid assignment.Check it once.Remove `k.luas;`

Comment: show another error after remove k.luas

`cannot find symbol`
Data_lingkaran k = new Data_lingkaran();